# remove thousand separator of number in CSV (batch command, using JREPL)

Tags: csv, batch-file, command, jrepl

I have the following csv where I have to replace the thousand comma separator with nothing. In example below, when I have the amount `"1,000.00"` I should have `1000.00` (no comma, no quotes) instead.

I use JREPL to remove header from my csv

```
jrepl "(?:.*\n){1,1}([\s\S]*)" "$1" /m /f "csv/Transactions.csv" /o "csv/Transactionsfeed.csv")
```

I was wondering if I could do the process of removing header + dealing with the thousand comma in one step.
I am also opened to the option of doing it with another command in a second step...

```
Tnx ID,Trace ID - Gateway,Profile,Customer PIN,Customer,Ext. ID,Identifier,Amount,Chrg,Curr,Processor,Type,Status,Created By,Date Created,RejectReason
1102845,3962708,SL,John,Mohammad Alo,NA,455015*****9998,900.00,900.00,$,Un,Credit Card,Rejected,Internet,2016-05-16 06:54:10,"-330: Fail by bank, try again later(refer to acquirer)"
1102844,3962707,SL,John,Mohammad Alo,NA,455015*****9998,"1,000.00","1,000.00",$,Un,Credit Card,Rejected,Internet,2016-05-16 06:52:26,"-330: Fail by bank, try again later(refer to acquirer)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a very efficient and fairly compact and straight-forward solution:

```
jrepl "\q(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d*)*)\q" "$1.replace(/,/g,'')" /x /j /jendln "if (ln==1) $txt=false" /f "csv/Transactions.csv" /o "csv/Transactionsfeed.csv"
```

The /JENDLN JScript expression strips the header line by setting $txt to false if it is the first line.

The search string matches any quoted number that contains commas as thousand separators, and $1 is the number without the quotes.

The replace string is a JScript expression that replaces all commas in the matching $1 number with nothing.

***EDIT***

Note that the above will likely work with any CSV that you are likely to have. However, it would fail if you have a quoted field that contains a quoted number string literal. Something like the following would yield a corrupted CSV with the code above:

```
...,"some text ""123,456.78"" more text",...
```

This issue can be fixed with a bit more regex code. You only want to modify a quoted number if the opening quote is preceded by a comma or the beginning of the line, and the closing quote should be followed by a comma or the end of line.

A look-ahead assertion can be used for the trailing comma/EOL. But JREPL does not support look-behind. So the leading comma/BOL must be captured and preserved in the replacement

```
jrepl "(^|,)\q(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d*)*)\q(?=$|,)" "$1+$2.replace(/,/g,'')" /x /j /jendln "if (ln==1) $txt=false" /f "csv/Transactions.csv" /o "csv/Transactionsfeed.csv"
```

***EDIT in response to changing requirement in comment***

The following will simply remove all quotes and commas from quoted CSV fields. I don't like this concept, and I suspect there is a much better way to handle this for import into mysql, but this is what the OP is asking for.

```
jrepl "(^|,)(\q(?:[^\q]|\q\q)*\q)(?=$|,)" "$1+$2.replace(/,|\x22/g,'')" /x /j /jendln "if (ln==1) $txt=false" /f "csv/Transactions.csv" /o "csv/Transactionsfeed.csv"
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly for the comma in thousands & the first row removal. I only noticed an error in case of a comma separated string between double quotes, as in this example: the field "Special Bonus, OK allan" makes it fail ("," in field should be erased too)
Tnx ID,Trace ID - Gateway,Profile,Customer PIN,Customer,Ext. ID,Identifier,Amount,Chrg,Curr,Processor,Type,Status,Created By,Date Created,RejectReason
1102921,,SL,jojo,Mohamed,"Special Bonus, OK allan",,200.00,200.00,$,ManualBonus,Generic,Approved,maurice,2016-05-16 15:26:26

Comment: @RenaudDUGERT - Huh! Why should all commas within quotes be removed? That certainly was not in your stated requirements. And blindly removing all commas from quoted fields could alter the meaning. I understand why you want to remove commas from numbers, but not all quoted commas. But that is certainly an easier problem to solve.

Comment: you are right... my mistake! but importing csv to mysql  makes things harder with commas in string. In this specific case, getting rid of any comma within a string (between double quotes) would be necessary...

Comment: Should all quotes be removed as well?

Comment: Yes sir! the quotes should also be removed. Thanks for your great help btw. Would be lost without this.

Comment: thanks dbenham. I really appreciate your help! greetings from Paris, France

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you a different, simpler solution? The 5-lines Batch file below do what you want; save it with .bat extension:

```
@set @a=0  /*
@cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < "csv/Transactions.csv" > "csv/Transactionsfeed.csv"
@goto :EOF */

WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/(\"(\d{1,3}),(\d{3}\.\d{2})\")/g,"$2$3"));
```

JREPL.BAT is a large and complex program capable of advanced replacement tasks; however, your request is very simple. This code is also a Batch-JScript hybrid script that use the `replace` method in the same way as JREPL.BAT, but that is tailored to your specific request.

- The first `ReadLine()` read the header line of the input file, so the posterior `ReadAll()` read and process the rest of lines.
- The regexp `(\"(\d{1,3}),(\d{3}\.\d{2})\")` define 3 submatches enclosed in parentheses: the first one is the whole number enclosed in quotes, like `"1,000.00"`; the second submatch is the digits before the comma and the third submatch is the digits after the comma, including the decimal point.
- The `.replace` method change the previous regexp, that is, *the whole number enclosed in quotes* by just the second and third submatches.

Comment: great solution. The only issue I get (my mistake!) what I mentionned to dbenham in that routine has also to get rid of commas in double quote string, such as "Special Bonus, OK allan" to "Special Bonus OK allan". any idea?

Comment: What happens if the number is `"1,234,567.89"`. This simplistic solution has an inherent limit to the number magnitude. Although the solution is simpler if all quoted commas are removed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. In this practical example, amounts should not be greater than 999,999.99, but it makes sense...